# Load JSON file modular view javascript approach

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, modular

I am trying to implement a modular view approach for calling a json file in my javascript code, but not able to rectify the issue. The code where I am calling json file is a separate js file which is as follows:

```
var fileConfigModule = (function () {

  var arData = {};

  function init() {
    loadJSON(function (json) {
      arData = json
    });
    return arData 
  }
  // Let's hide this function

  function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', './data.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        arVals= callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
      }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
  }

  return {
    loadJSON: loadJSON,
    init: init
  }
})();
```

I want to use this module in my main file to get the json loaded from file something like this aysnc. This uses a call back function.

```
var arData = fileConfigModule.init();
```

Please if someone can help, what I am doing wrong here. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling an async function but expecting return value as sync function.

Update your code as below,

```
var fileConfigModule = (function () {

  function init(callback) {
    loadJSON(function (json) {
      callback(json);
    });
  }
  // Let's hide this function

  function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', './data.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
      }
    };
    xobj.send();
  }

  return {
    loadJSON: loadJSON,
    init: init
  }
})();
```

And call as below,

```
var arData = null;
fileConfigModule.init(function(data){
  arData = data;
});
```

I don't know why you're trying to hide `loadJSON` function. But I think you should directly use the `loadJSON` function, instead of calling the `init` function.

Calling `loadJSON`,

```
var arData = null;
fileConfigModule.loadJSON(function(data){
  arData = data;
});
```

Comment: This works for me perfectly. Can you explain me a bit more, why this works, why do you have an extra call for call back? 

And how do i directly call loadJSON function in the similar example? or the best way this should be written?

Comment: I have updated my answer with calling `loadJSON` function approach.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am trying to get my head round to the callback functions and exactly how it works.

Comment: This may help you: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced.